# DB level constraints to validate 1 field against another one in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is it any way to use Django constraint in model (`models.CheckConstraint`
class) in order to create a constraint to validate value of one field against another one?

For example:

```
class Season(models.Model):
last_watched_episode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    null=True,
)
number_of_episodes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(

)
```

In this case I need to make a constraint that would raise an error in case value of 
the `last_watched_episode` field is greater then `number_of_episodes` field.
9 > 8 for example. Plus in case if `last_watched_episode is Null`(**none**) constrain should be omitted ( cant compare **Null** and **int**)

I have model and serializer validators already but goal is to create DB level constraints.
Way to create it with RAW SQL and custom migration is also possible but via DJANGO constraints would be preferable.
Thank you.
DB -postgres 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that it is possible o use `F`in constraints:

```
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
           models.CheckConstraint(name='mutual_watched_episode_and_number_of_episodes_check',
check = (models.Q(number_of_episodes__gte=models.F('last_watched_episode')))
            ),
        ]
```

This way it works